# How would I run that SQL in Magento way using collections?

Tags: magento, collections

This is my SQL:

```
select created_at from sales_flat_order where created_at > SUBDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
```

This is returning me the orders from the last 3 hours. Now, how would I run that query using Magento collection?

This is what I have so far:

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

Now I need to add some filter, but I am stuck there. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look @ [Using Collections in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
    'gt' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUBDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)'))
```

or

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orderCollection->getSelect()->where('created_at > SUBDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)');
```

Comment: I had almost the same code, except for the "new Zend_Db_Expr". Thanks!

Comment: @R.S just 1 min slower than you :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 10800; // 3hr(60min/hr)(60sec/min)
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$order =Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
    ->load();
```

Let me know if you have any query